Tethering usb reaching lan
I have a question.
My phone is connected to a router to share the connection via tethering usb.
Phone -- ISP ip = random
-- tethering interface (rndis0) = ip random
Router -- ip client random
-- lan ip 192.168.178.1
I would like from my phone to reach my LAN.
At the moment pinging 192.168.178.1 from the phone doesn't work.
Is it possible to do without fixing IPs that are random above?
The phone is a rooted Pixel with Android 12.
Thanks for reading and the help.
